# ImportError: Install adlfs to access Azure Datalake Gen2 and Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am using Spyder and I am running the following code:

import pandas

```
storage_options={'account_name': 'bidi', 'account_key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}

df = pandas.read_csv('abfs://taxi@bidi.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/taxi_zone.csv', storage_options=storage_options)

print(df)
```

But this is giving me the following error:

```
ImportError: Install adlfs to access Azure Datalake Gen2 and Azure Blob Storage
```

So I opened Anaconda Prompt as administrator and typed:

```
Conda install adlfs
```

I received the following error:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install adlfs
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - adlfs

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: Try `python -m pip install adlfs` instead

Comment: I ended up doing this:
Install the adlfs package via 'Command Prompt'
pip install adlfs

Navigate to the Python directory where the newly installed packages are and manually copy them into the Anaconda directory. There should be around 20 folders.

But your method is much easier. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your conda prompt, you'll want to use:

```bash
python -m pip install adlfs
```